# How to add values ​from a table in a LARAVEL resource

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know if someone can help me, I do not know how I can add a total amount of items in my shopping cart, I need to count how many items (sum of quantities) the cart carries, every item in the cart have a value for quantity.

So far in my collection I have:

//this part is to get the data in the specific cart, I used to have `->where('cart_id', '=', $cart->id)->first()` but of course just took the first value

```
 $cart = $request->route('cart');
    $data = DB::table('cart_items')
        ->where('cart_id', '=', $cart->id)
        ->get()->toArray();
```

//here it should makes a cycle and obtains and adds the quantity value for each item stored in that cart,

```
foreach ($data as $dat)
    $quant = $dat->quantity;
    $sum = 0;
    $total = $quant + $sum;
```

And $total should return a number with the whole add of quantities in the cart

```
 return [
        'Items' => $this->collection,
        'each_count' => $total,
    ];
```

the problem is that $total is returning 1, and not the sum of quantities.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You are only adding the quantity of your last item with 0, which gives you 1.

First of all, you have to wrap your loop with brackets.

```
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    // ...
}
```

Secondly, you then have to declare `$total` outside the loop so it does not get overwritten on each iteration.

```
$total = 0;

foreach ($data as $dat) {
    // ...
}
```

And lastly, update the total instead of assigning it inside your loop:

```
$total = 0;

foreach ($data as $dat) {
    $quantity = $dat->quantity;
    $sum = 0;
    $total += $quantity + $sum;
}
```

Not sure why your sum is hardcoded to zero though.

---

### Method 2

If you only need the sum of the quantities, you can do `$data->sum('quantity');` without looping through your items.

Comment: Thank you! You are rigth, I forgot the $total = 0; before, also, my $sum is not 
necessary, and I was using endforeach haha :x you save me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you want sum of quantities you can use basic function sum() 
    $data->sum('$quantity');